# What library can I use to send SMTP/MIME emails containing UTF text and file attachments with?

Tags: c++, smtp, g++

I was looking for a library to send e-mails in SMTP/MIME format to send Unicode text and file attachments. My application uses the Qt framework and I'm compiling using g++.

After searching the web I found [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) but it needs MS Visual Studio to be built. What libraries are available (which will compile using g++) to send SMTP/MIME format emails containing UTF encoded text and file attachments?

Comment: If it's windows only, consider CDOSYS.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, but actually my development environment is windows, my target is cross-platform application, that's why I used Qt.

Comment: "Basic support for building with MinGW is there as well, but at this time is not officially supported and may or may not work." http://pocoproject.org/docs/99150-WindowsPlatformNotes.html. I suggest you try building POCO yourself under MinGW and linking statically with POCO_STATIC defined, you may have better luck.

Comment: @Styne666 my question is _what_ library can I use to send SMTP/MIME emails from Qt?

Comment: I'm not sure why Qt is pertinent information. You simply need a [C++ smtp library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/58210/594137). Then you pass it data converted to narrow or wide character arrays (which the QString class does in your case).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and I found the exact thing I was looking for in github.
Maybe I'm little late to help you @mezo but I'll leave the link here so anybody comming from a search in google can find it.

https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt